# Grabbing file name from a command line argument in C++ console app

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a console app that takes a few command line arguments, one of which is a file name, and outputs a different file.

I want to pull the name from the argument so I can incorporate it into the output file name. For example, I start with potato.txt, and when I run the executable, it outputs 1234potato.txt. If I run it again with tomato.txt, it will output 1234tomato.txt.

The problem I'm running into is that

```
*argv[1] //only gets the first char of "potato.txt"
```

I need a way to grab the whole thing. How do people usually do this?
Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ `char*` *are* strings, just like in C, because strings are arrays of characters, and arrays are sometimes handled using a pointer to its first member. But if you dereference the pointer you'll get only the first character. Do instead:

```
std::string(argv[1])
```

Or, depending on the context, you can use `argv[1]` directly. Many functions that can take a string as argument can also take a `const char *`. And even if they are not overloaded, in most cases the compiler will add a temporary variable for you.

Or if you want to give the variable a meaningful name:

```
char *filename = argv[1];
```

Or if you want to have a variable *and* use the `string` class:

```
std::string filename(argv[1]);
```

**UPDATE**: From your comments below you have the following error:

> C2440: "initializing': cannot convert from '_TCHAR*' to 'char*'

That means that `_TCHAR` and `char` are not the same type (`_TCHAR` is actually a typedef of `wchar_t`). It also means that `argv` is of type `_TCHAR**`. All that means that you have created a Microsoft Unicode project.

This is a quite non-standard *extension* of C by MS to make your programs Unicode aware. For example, instead of a `main` function you have a `_tmain` function, that is actually a macro that expands continionally to `wmain` or `main`, depending on the Unicode options of the project.  The prototypes of these functions will be  `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

You have basically two options:

- Disable all the UNICODE options in the project options. Then, `_TCHAR` will revert to its clasical definition of `char` and all will be normal. But you will loose the Unicode capabilites.
- Do the UNICODE way. Then you should use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, `wchar_t` instead of `char`, `L"hello"` instead of `"hello"`, etc. This way lies madness!

Comment: Hm, VS2010 says "no instance of constructor ... matches the argument list" What's happening here?

Comment: @user2864293: Mmmm... weird. You should post the whole error message (there are useful information in the compiler messages).and a minimal code example that shows this behavior. Chances are that you have some mistake in another part of your program.

Comment: Using 
    `char *filename = argv[1];` throws the following errors

1) error C2440: "initializing': cannot convert from '_TCHAR*' to 'char*'
2)IntelliSense: a value of type "_TCHAR cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char*"

Comment: @user2864293: Ah! You are another victim of the Windows Unicode craziness. Please see my updated answer.